# Задание по Регулярному выражению, oracle sql

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать такой запрос:

"Используя регулярные выражения напишите запрос, который выведет все адреса (addr1) где 7ой символ O или R"

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d46a7df717a38c4a9722d01374bb577e)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и пример вставки данных, начало
create table tbl (addr1 varchar2(100));

insert into tbl (addr1) 
select 'FOUR CROWNS' from dual
union all select 'TERMOBOAT' from dual;
-- DDL и пример вставки данных, конец

select *
from tbl
where REGEXP_INSTR(addr1, 'R|O', 7,1,0,'i') = 7;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли. Решение сработало.

Comment: Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает для вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить его как ответ.

Comment: новый человек здесь, не знал, что значит "пометить, как ответ". сейчас сделал) спасибо еще раз